# How to save start time of all the individual samples in my jmeter test and use that in JSR223 Listener

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, influxdb, beanshell

Im using **influxfb** to save the result of my **jmeter test**.

bellow is the part of code in **JSR223 Listener** where im in need of your help.

```
result = new StringBuilder();

result.append("Thro_5,")   

.append("label=")
.append(escapeValue(sampleResult.getSampleLabel()))


result.append("count=")
count=sampleResult.getSampleCount();
result.append(count)


result.append(",duration=")

dur1=sampleResult.getStartTime();
result.append(sampleResult.getEndTime()-sampleResult.getStartTime())
```

*****here code to write data to influxdb*****

I'm trying this code in which i want to know the total duration sample has taken till now to calculate throughput.

```
    a=sampleResult.getEndTime()-sampleResult.getStartTime()
    .append(",throughput_=")
    .append(totalSamplecount/(a/1000))
```

Last line in the above code , i.e sampleResult.getStartTime()  ,it should be the starting time of a sample in the first loop.

If i have 3 samples in my test ,having loop count 3 ,i want to save the starting time of each sample in the first iteration and use that value in the calculation of throughput of each samples.

Then while i'm in 3rd loop i want to know the total duration it has taken so far from the first iteration.And `totalsamplecount/duration`

As far as i know sampleResult holds the result of current sample.

I'm stuck in 2 points:

1. in saving the start time of each samples and use it later for each iteration to calculate the duration.
2. In saving the total count of individual samples executed till now.

Comment: not sure I entirely follow what you're trying to do.

Comment: It can be done, but it's a really bad idea: if your listener will keep saving data for each and every sampler, however the small data is, it will be large with many parallel users/samples. In addition, the more calculations you add, the more CPU/memory listener will need and everything else will slow down. And if listener is slower than samplers, then it will become a bottleneck. So I would recommend to save a raw data, only what you need, and make calculations in DB, or using awk, etc.

Comment: @ Kiril S , can u please tell me how can it be done.